# Работа с tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Есть html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tooltip</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css_tooltip.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div class="color_box">
        <a href="#" class="radio" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;" title="Алюминий">
            <input type="radio" name="color" style="opacity: 0;">
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="radio graize" style="background-color: #F5F5DC; " title="Бежевый" >
            <input type="radio" name="color" style="opacity: 0;">
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="radio" style="background-color: #964B00; " title="Коричневый" >
            <input type="radio" name="color" style="opacity: 0;">
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="radio graize" style="background-color: #98FB98; " title="Светло-зеленый" >
            <input type="radio" name="color" style="opacity: 0;">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="box_b">
        <a href="/cat/000088602" class="radio radio3 radio_act graize">
            <input type="radio" name="filter_second" style="opacity: 0;">
                        1
        </a>
        <a href="/cat/000088602" class="radio radio3 radio_act">
            <input type="radio" name="filter_second" style="opacity: 0;">
                        2
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript"  src="tooltip/jquery.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript"  src="tooltip/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript"  src="tooltip/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tooltip/tooltip.js"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Написан код для tooltipa

```
$('.graize').tooltip({
    track: true,
    items: 'a',
    show: { effect: "blind"},
    content: function() {return "Привет" + " " + $(this).attr('title');} 
});
```

Он работает, если есть класс graize, для цветов выводит все как надо, а вот для ссылки,в которой цифра, "Привет undefined" , как вытащить значение из тега a?

Comment: ну так там где цифры, вы title не задаёте. а в скрипте обращаетесь прямо к нему (title)

Comment: Естественно `title` - `undefined`, у ссылок не указан этот атрибут

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо, вопрос решил.

```
{return "Недоступно в" + " " + $(this).text();}
```

Вроде работает)